# How can I get python to interpret a string as python code?

Tags: python, django

I have written a function in Django to look up an object based on its type that works akin to the following:

```
def lookup(modelType, item_id):
    try:
        return eval(modelType).objects.get(pk=item_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return None
```

`lookup(Course, 14)` should return `Course.objects.get(pk=14)` if there is a Course object with ID 14.

Is this function feasible to write? Thank you.

Comment: Did you not try this before asking your question? Although eval is discouraged, this should have worked.

Comment: @Marcin: It won't work with the `lookup(Course, 14)` code supplied, however.

Comment: I had tried it, but I was concerned about security.

Comment: "security"?  What do you think you mean by "security" as a concern with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `lookup(Course, 14)` then do this.

```
def lookup( the_model, item_id ):
    try:
        the_model.objects.get( pk=item_id )
    except the_model.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

If you want to keep using the function you wrote, then you have to pass the model as a string.

`lookup( "Course", 14)`

Also.  `return None` is a very bad idea.  It's usually much better to use exceptions properly.

Comment: Thanks! What does it mean to use exceptions properly?

Comment: eval(modelType) is a much worse idea than swallowing exceptions. Requiring a string suggests that the caller doesn't have much control over the parameters, and eval is probably the worst thing to do in that situation. The only thing that I would change about the exception handling is to `pass` on the exception, and let the function return `None` implicitly (or don't even mention the exception and let it propagate up)

Comment: @IanClelland: "Requiring a string suggests that the caller doesn't have much control over the parameters".  Not true at all.  It could come from a configuration file that's quite secure.

Answer (score 2):

Eval (or exec) is way too dangerous for this kind of usage. You're better off creating a mapping between models and a string. For example:

```
from school.models import Student, Teacher

model_mapping = {'student': Student,
                 'teacher': Teacher}
```

If a string is given, you can do:

```
string_of_a_model = 'student'
model_mapping[string_of_a_model].objects.all()
```